# change select box to autocomplete jquery source php echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

Need your help

I want change select box with autocomplete jquery 
here my worked select box

```
<select name="sShippingPayment" title="simple;<?php echo $lang['Select_shipping_and_payment']; ?>" onchange="countShippingPrice( this )" id="oShippingPayment">
<option value=""><?php echo $lang['Select']; ?></option>
<?php echo $sShippingPaymentSelect; ?>
</select>
```

and here my code for jquery

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<p><label>Shipping & Payment:</label><input type='text' name='sShippingPayment' value='' class='auto'></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
//autocomplete
$(".auto").autocomplete({
source: <?php echo $sShippingPaymentSelect; ?>,
minLength: 1
}); 

});
```

but it won't work, please help me out.

I check on php file

```
  * Returns shipping and payment select
  * @return string
  */
  public function throwShippingPaymentsSelect( ){
    $aShipping = $this->throwPaymentsShipping( 2 );
    $aPayments = $this->throwPaymentsShipping( 1 );
    if( isset( $aShipping ) && isset( $aPayments ) ){
      $content = null;
      foreach( $aShipping as $iShipping => $aData ){
        if( isset( $aData['aPayments'] ) ){
          foreach( $aData['aPayments'] as $iPayment => $sPriceModify ){
            if( isset( $aPayments[$iPayment] ) ){
              $fShippingPaymentPrice = !empty( $sPriceModify ) ? generatePrice( $aData['fPrice'], $sPriceModify ) : $aData['fPrice'];
              $content .= 
              '<option value="'.$iShipping.';'.$iPayment.';'.$fShippingPaymentPrice.'">'.
                $aData['sName'].' : Rp. '.
                displayPrice( $fShippingPaymentPrice )
              .'</option>';
            }
          } // end foreach
        }
      } // end foreach
      return $content;
    }
  } // end function throwShippingPaymentsSelect
```

should I need to change

```
      $content .= 
      '<option value="'.$iShipping.';'.$iPayment.';'.$fShippingPaymentPrice.'">'.
        $aData['sName'].' : Rp. '.
        displayPrice( $fShippingPaymentPrice )
      .'</option>';
```

to be read as autocomplete source? please help how to change that.

Really thanks for your answer.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? What's it doing now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methinks you need to wrap your php echo output in quotation marks:

```
//autocomplete
$(".auto").autocomplete({
source: <?php echo '"' . $sShippingPaymentSelect . '"'; ?>,
minLength: 1
});
```

But without a description of "it wont work", we can't help you much further.

Comment: It is a little cleaner to wrap it like `source: "<?php echo $sShippingPaymentSelect; ?>",`

Comment: Sure, whatever floats your boat. This is one of those situations where readability sucks either way. Honestly, I'd add the quotes straight to the variable value itself.

Comment: thanks dudewad and sean, both source: <?php echo '"' . $sShippingPaymentSelect . '"'; ?>,  &  source: "<?php echo $sShippingPaymentSelect; ?>", still not work on my side. this line <?php echo $sShippingPaymentSelect; ?> printed well on browser, but autocomplete script still cannot grab it. here my trial website http://reseller.site50.net/?order-form,16